# Using jAlert for a confirm delete alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a routine that performs a `Form` action if **OK** is clicked on a webpage `alert`:

SCRIPT

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkDelete(){
return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form action="https://website/delUser.php" method="Post">
<input value="Delete" type="submit" onclick="return checkDelete()" class="submitButton">
</form>
```

In an attempt to make the alert a little more attractive I have tried to use `jAlert`:

JALERT SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function()
{
  $("#confirm_button").click( function()
  {
    jConfirm('Delete this user?', 'Title', function(result) 
    {
     jAlert('Pressed: ' + result, 'Results'); //This displays the result as an alert - true or false
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The new alert displays but I am unsure how to change the HTML so that the `Form` action only runs if the alert returns true.

Comment: Can't get it. Can you explain a bit more what you try to achieve?

Comment: When the button is pressed the alert pops up saying "'Are you sure you want to delete this record?". The first method works and if the user presses OK then the Form action continues. If they press Cancel then nothing happens. I want to do the same but using jalerts as they are more attractive.

Comment: You do postback on delete?

Comment: And this posts back what to where? I am sorry - first time using this.

Comment: Can you post html structure?

Comment: I have added a bit more HTML - is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
<form name="test_form" action="action.php">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="submitButton" id="confirm_button">
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#confirm_button").click( function()
{
    jConfirm('Delete this user?', 'Title', function(result) 
    {
        if(result){
            // FORM ACTION HERE
            test_form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But I want to return to where the button was clicked in the HTML rather perform the action from within the javascript.

Comment: This does not work - it does not wait for the user to respond to the jconfirm but just continues with the form action deleting the record.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit. You have to remove the type="submit". I hope this helps in someway.

Comment: Weel, with better completion, something like that would be my aproach. Hope helps you.. good luck